# Aggregating .Net Core appsettings.json

Tags: json, .net-core, configuration, appsettings, sln-file

I have multiple project under the same solution. My concern is the following:

Is there any way to aggregate all `appsettings.json` from different projects into one file in the same solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, use may use "Add as Link" feature (for other code editors, change .csproj manually as described after image):

- put your 'appsettings.json' into solution folder (one level higher from project folder) for example;
- for each project in solution:

  1. right-click project name in Solution Explorer
  2. in context menu: Add -> Existing item (Shift + Alt + A)
  3. navigate to appsettings.json file
  4. use drop-down of "Add" button and click "Add as link" (see screenshot below)
  5. you will see "appsettings.json" added to your project with small arrow on icon
  6. right-click that file, click Properties, and set "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer".

[image: Image of "Add as Link" button option]

After you save you project, you will see this new lines in .csproj file (add them manually if you use code editor other than VS, without "Add as link" option):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\appsettings.json" Link="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

After that, building that project (from VS or with 'dotnet build') puts "appsettings.json" into your output build folder.